# WCF configuration and authentication nightmare

Tags: wcf-security

I am working with windows server 2008 r2 running iis 7.5.  My WCF service is running on framework 4.0.  32-bit app running integrated pipeline.

Service is in a virtual directory with Annonymous and Windows Authentication enabled.  My configuration looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyWebservice.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyWebservice.MyServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="MyWebservice.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWebservice.MyServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I connect with the WCF Test Client from an account that is on the domain, I get the following exception:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.

This error is profoundly un-helpful.  Can anyone point me to the error of my ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot fixed the error.  When will I ever learn, with Windows... when things stop making sense, reboot.